# A basic query on sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a  group of odd order then $2 \not\mid\ \lvert G \rvert$, so can we say that $G$ has a sylow $2$- subgroup which is $\{e\}$ or a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is only defined if $p \mid \lvert G \rvert$?

Comment: We can say that $\{ e \}$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. But you need to be careful, because some books fail to consider this case when they make general statements about Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Yes, it's like saying that $17$ divides $24$ with exponent $0$, that is $v_{17}(24)=0$, which is true and useful.